# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

Tags: php

Hi I am a new student in Php,. I am currently developing a login.php

But after compiling i am getting this error message,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\uploadthis\login.php on line 90
```

My login.php file is given below

```
<?php   session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE["usNick"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usPass"])){ ?>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=myaccount.php">
<?php 
    exit();
}

$display_error = "";
$username = "";

if ($_POST['username']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if( strtolower($_POST['code'])!= strtolower($_SESSION['texto'])){ 
        $display_error = "* Security Code Error"; // error language
        include ('error.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        include('includes/config.inc.php');
        $username=uc($_POST['username']);
        $pass=uc($_POST['password']);
        $password = sha1($pass);

        if ($password==NULL) {
            $display_error = "* All fields are required"; // error language
            include ('error.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            $myDb->connect();
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM yob_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
                $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $myDb->close();
            if($data['password'] != $password) {
                $display_error = "* Please, Check your username/password."; // error language
                include ('error.php');
                exit();
            }else{
                $myDb->connect();
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM yob_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $myDb->close();
                $nicke=$row['username'];
                $passe=$row['password'];
                setcookie("usNick",$nicke,time()+7776000);
                setcookie("usPass",$passe,time()+7776000);
                $lastlogdate = date("F j, Y - g:i a");
                $lastip = getRealIP();
                $myDb->connect();
                    $querybt = "UPDATE yob_users SET lastlogdate='$lastlogdate', lastiplog='$lastip' WHERE username='$nicke'";
                    mysql_query($querybt) or die(mysql_error());
                $myDb->close(); ?> 
                <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=myaccount.php">
<?
            }
        }
    }
}else{ 
    include ('header.php'); 
?>
        <div id="content">
            <p class="error"><?php echo $display_error;?></p>

          <form action="login.php" method="post" class="f-wrap-1">
          <div class="req"><a href="signup.php">Not Registered?</a><br /><a href="recoverpass.php">Forgot your Password?</a></div>
          <fieldset>

          <h3>Member Login</h3>

            <label for="firstname"><b>Username:</b>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" /><br />
            </label>
            <label for="password"><b>Password:</b>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" /><br />
            </label>
            <label for="code"><b>Security Code:</b>
            <input id="code" name="code" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" /><br />
            </label>
            <label for="code2"><b>&nbsp;</b>
            <img src="image.php?<?php echo $res; ?>" /><br />
            </label>
            <div class="f-submit-wrap">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="f-submit" tabindex="4" /><br />
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>

<?php
include ('footer.php'); 
}
}
?>
```

I have closed with

> }
>   But still getting error,. but couldn't get it workerd. Please help.

Comment: Instead of closing PHP and outputting a meta refresh tag use `header("location: myaccount.php"); exit();`

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove last bracket. added "php tag" after

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=myaccount.php">
 <?
```

My recommendation is to use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* function. For the security and mysql_* is depreciated.

debug for your code:

```
       <?php   session_start();
            if(isset($_COOKIE["usNick"]) && isset($_COOKIE["usPass"])){ ?>
                <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=myaccount.php">
            <?php 
                exit();
            }

            $display_error = "";
            $username = "";

            if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                if( strtolower($_POST['code'])!= strtolower($_SESSION['texto'])){ 
                    $display_error = "* Security Code Error"; // error language
                    include ('error.php');
                    exit();
                }else{
                    include('includes/config.inc.php');
                    $username=uc($_POST['username']);
                    $pass=uc($_POST['password']);
                    $password = sha1($pass);

                    if ($password==NULL) {
                        $display_error = "* All fields are required"; // error language
                        include ('error.php');
                        exit();
                    }else{
                        $myDb->connect();
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM yob_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
                            $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                        $myDb->close();
                        if($data['password'] != $password) {
                            $display_error = "* Please, Check your username/password."; // error language
                            include ('error.php');
                            exit();
                        }else{
                            $myDb->connect();
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM yob_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
                                $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                            $myDb->close();
                            $nicke=$row['username'];
                            $passe=$row['password'];
                            setcookie("usNick",$nicke,time()+7776000);
                            setcookie("usPass",$passe,time()+7776000);
                            $lastlogdate = date("F j, Y - g:i a");
                            $lastip = getRealIP();
                            $myDb->connect();
                                $querybt = "UPDATE yob_users SET lastlogdate='$lastlogdate', lastiplog='$lastip' WHERE username='$nicke'";
                                mysql_query($querybt) or die(mysql_error());
                            $myDb->close(); ?> 
                            <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=myaccount.php">
            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{ 
                include ('header.php'); 
            ?>
                    <div id="content">
                        <p class="error"><?php echo $display_error;?></p>

                      <form action="login.php" method="post" class="f-wrap-1">
                      <div class="req"><a href="signup.php">Not Registered?</a><br /><a href="recoverpass.php">Forgot your Password?</a></div>
                      <fieldset>

                      <h3>Member Login</h3>

                        <label for="firstname"><b>Username:</b>
                        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" /><br />
                        </label>
                        <label for="password"><b>Password:</b>
                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" /><br />
                        </label>
                        <label for="code"><b>Security Code:</b>
                        <input id="code" name="code" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" /><br />
                        </label>
                        <label for="code2"><b>&nbsp;</b>
                        <img src="image.php?<?php echo $res; ?>" /><br />
                        </label>
                        <div class="f-submit-wrap">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="f-submit" tabindex="4" /><br />
                        </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        </form>

            <?php
            include ('footer.php'); 
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: when i delete the last } it didn't make any difference, Should I just copy paste the solution that you gave me?

Comment: Okay, after copy+paste it worked but got a new error,

`Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\xampp\htdocs\uploadthis\login.php on line 11~`

Comment: yes, just copy paste the code

Comment: That is not an error, it is notice for the reason of $_POST['username'] is not set thats why. I have updated the code with isset($_POST['username'])

Comment: This answer is vulnerable to SQL injection. Don't use it.

Comment: Yes. It seems that the script has too many bugs to be solved. For example the pages under my account are all so buggy that It would take life time simply to make everything work as fine. but still it remains too vulnerable to be hacked, So i dropped the project. Thanks for help by the way.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/19752683/2948532?sem=2 @MarcelKorpel ,

Comment: @ChinnuR Please rate my questtion./